# How to make a cookie when somebody click on bootstrap accordion panel?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a cookie, when somebody click on bootstrap accordion panel.

Thanks

Comment: Which part are you stuck on, creating the cookie, or responding to the click?

Comment: And if you only need this information client-side, don't use a cookie. Use web storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i found solution for that

```
<script>
$(".openpanel").on("click", function() {
    $("#panel3").collapse('show');
$.cookie("test", 1);

});
$(".closepanel").on("click", function() {
    $("#panel3").collapse('hide');
});

/* ensure any open panels are closed before showing selected */
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
    $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
});
</script>




<button type="button" class="btn openpanel">Open panel 3</button>
<button type="button" class="btn closepanel">Close panel 3</button>
<hr>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel1">Panel 1</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel2">Panel 2</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#panel3">Panel 3</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="panel3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Contents panel 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a [cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) in Javascript with `document.cookie = 'value';`

Add the code to the click event on the accordion panel.

*Note: iff that's the part you're stuck at, add your code :)*